# decode video frames into OpenGL textures with FFmpeg -> QSV -> glTexImage2D

Tags: opengl, optimization, ffmpeg, intel, hardware-acceleration

Is anyone aware of the most accelerated route of binding an AVFrame returned from ffmpeg avcodec_receive_frame when using [Intel Quick Sync Video (QSV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video) to an OpenGL texture?

I'm using ffmpeg's QSV decode and mapping a NV12 returned frame to a software buffer via av_hwframe_map to allow the OpenGL creation of two planes (NV12) as two textures for GLSL pixel shader colour conversion and more on route to display.

Is this the fastest route using the two frameworks?

Native QSV via dx9 + HLSL is much faster.

I've seen some OpenCL extensions for surface mapping. Any pointers are interesting to know. Note, QSV decoded frames have advantages as they may not reside in dedicated gc video memory as a thought.

Comment: Does VAAPI do this?  Maybe have a look at what MPV uses (https://mpv.io) - its `gpu` video output can take advantage of HW decode but then does high-quality scaling using OpenGL shaders.  (I don't know the details, but it's GPL open-source.  I just use it on my Linux desktop, Skylake graphics.  Its `gpu` video-output used to be called `opengl`, but it still uses OpenGL + VAAPI to HW decode h.264, h.265, VP9, etc.)

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll take a look at the source and report back.